# Modify DataFrame passed as argument

Tags: python, pandas

I have a timeseries DataFrame (df) to which i need to add an column, and then pass this df to a function that modifies the content of a time slice of a single column.
My idea is as follows:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=3, freq='H')
df= pd.DataFrame([0,0,0],columns=['A'],index=rng)
df['B']=0

def v(dff,n):
    dff.loc[rng[0]:rng[1],:].B=n
```

As far as I understand python argument passing, the call to v(df,n) should modify the DataFrame but the problem is that id does not do it all the time.

The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
v(df,1)
print("Ater first: ", df)
v(df,2)
print("After second: ", df)

('Ater first: ',                      A  B
2011-01-01 00:00:00  0  0
2011-01-01 01:00:00  0  0
2011-01-01 02:00:00  0  0

[3 rows x 2 columns])
('After second: ',                      A  B
2011-01-01 00:00:00  0  2
2011-01-01 01:00:00  0  2
2011-01-01 02:00:00  0  0
```

which is surprising, because i would expect column B to be ether  0,0,0, or first 1,1,0, and then 2,2,0.

The things get stranger if i put a single print(df) BEFORE the first call to v. The code:

```
print("Before: ", df)
v(df,1)
print("Ater first: ", df)
v(df,2)
print("After second: ", df)

Produces:
('Before: ',                      A  B
2011-01-01 00:00:00  0  0
2011-01-01 01:00:00  0  0
2011-01-01 02:00:00  0  0

[3 rows x 2 columns])
('Ater first: ',                      A  B
2011-01-01 00:00:00  0  1
2011-01-01 01:00:00  0  1
2011-01-01 02:00:00  0  0

[3 rows x 2 columns])
('After second: ',                      A  B
2011-01-01 00:00:00  0  2
2011-01-01 01:00:00  0  2
2011-01-01 02:00:00  0  0
```

So the result depends on whether i print a df ferore the call to the function that modifies it!

This happens if and only if I add new column to the df, take a time range slice and then modify that column. If I create a DataFrame with 2 columns in the first place, then things work as expected.

What is going on? Is this a bug in pandas or in python or is it that my understanding of how things work in python is fundamentally wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you create a frame of a single dtype it is a view. If you create it then add a column, it is not. This is the reason for the difference in assignment behavior. @EdChum answer gives a higher level reason while you should not rely on this behavior and just use loc always speciying all indexing dimensions.

Comment: Thanks. @EdChum your solution works, although it still bothers me, why printing a data frame before the call changes the behaviour completely.

Comment: has nothing to do with printing, and 100% to do with whether a view is generated by numpy or not. You really need to read the pointed to section by @EdChum

Comment: Jeff's comment explains the difference in behaviour, these subtle differences is why you should follow the coding practice in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is to do with [`chain indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) which sometimes work, if you change your function line to this:

```
def v(dff,n):
    dff.loc[rng[0]:rng[1],'B']=n
```

Then it works as expected, this is the recommended semantic for assignment that works in all cases.